# htaccess taking me back to index every time

Tags: .htaccess

I have set htaccess, but it's taking me back to my index file every time:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ en/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^en/search/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /en/search/search.php?search_name=$1&mydropdown=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My URLs are:

```
**getting data from Index.php**
http://myweb.com/en/?pno=2 
http://myweb.com/en/?pno=3
http://myweb.com/en/?pno=4 ect..

**getting data from search.php**
http://myweb.com/en/search/?search_name=white&mydropdown=All+Categories
http://myweb.com/en/search/?search_name=pink&mydropdown=All+Categories
http://myweb.com/en/search/?search_name=blue&mydropdown=All+Categories ect....
```

Comment: This is rewriting EVERY request? Can you give an example of a URL that it is rewriting that you do NOT want it to rewrite?

Comment: Your second rule is odd in that it you are referencing a second parenthesized subpattern ($2), but there is only one set of parenthesis. This is not related to your problem through.

Comment: i try to explain above, please check it.

Comment: Did you try inverting the order of the rules? `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` will match `"search"` too.

Comment: done everything no success....